# Eclipse cannot commit and push due to error: C:\Users\userpath\.ssh access is denied

Tags: windows, eclipse, github, ssh, egit

Disclaimer: I am new to using git/github so if I get things wrong please correct me.

I have my eclipse java projects under a private github repository using ssh keys with passphrase and I am connected through EGit. The purpose of this is to allow me to work on my projects across devices (current device being windows and other device being macbook pro, which I got this working with already). However, when I refactor a project and attempt to commit and push I get this error.

```
Can't connect to any repository: ssh://git@github.com/[githubaccount]/dev.git (Cannot run program "C:\Users\Jmbaffo\.ssh": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied)
```

I've read through maybe every other thread available on this topic and none so far have helped, I've set PATH variables pointing to my .ssh folder but after doing that this error occurs.

**EDIT** 
Ok, so I don't even know how my computer was functioning without this but apparently my HOME PATH variable wasn't even set. I realized this when I viewed the error log in eclipse (where console appears). So I added a new PATH: `HOME` to `C:\Users\Jmbaffo\` and voilà, I was able to get it working. I also stopped using staging view and just use the context menu when I right click on the repository.

Comment: Eclipse must read private and public SSH keys which are stored in the directory `C:\Users\Jmbaffo\.ssh`. So check your Windows file/directory permissions.

Comment: The error implies that git is trying to invoke your `.ssh` directory as if it were a program. How have you configured git? Is your GIT_SSH environment variable set to something?

Comment: Yes, my GIT_SSH enviro variable is set to `C:\Users\Jmbaffo\.ssh`, I just don't know how to give eclipse the necessary permissions to invoke the .ssh directory. I also forgot to mention that my eclipse installation is in `C:\dev` and not in any program files folders.

Comment: @Jmbaffo @Kenster If you use the _Git Staging_ view to commit and push (not the command line outside of Eclipse), [`GIT_SSH` is not read](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Environment) (Eclipse has its own Git implementation). Which settings do you have in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_?

Comment: Under _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_ I have SSH2 Home set to `C:\Users\Jmbaffo\.ssh` and my private keys are `id_dsa,id_rsa` and if it means anything my highest preferred authentication method is `gssapi-with-mic`

Comment: Are we allowed to bump here or is that against rules?